# ES6: Create Strings using Template LiteralsPassed Freecodecamp

Tags: javascript, html, css

[Create Strings using Template LiteralsPassed](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/es6/create-strings-using-template-literals)

```
const result = {
  success: ["max-length", "no-amd", "prefer-arrow-functions"],
  failure: ["no-var", "var-on-top", "linebreak"],
  skipped: ["id-blacklist", "no-dup-keys"]
};
function makeList(arr) {
  "use strict";

  // Only change code below this line
  const resultDisplayArray = (arr) =>{
    let failure = [];
    for (element of arr) {
      failure.push(`<li class="text-warning">${element}</li>`);
    }
    console.log(failure);
    return failure;
    
  };
  // Only change code above this line

  return resultDisplayArray;
}

const resultDisplayArray = makeList(result.failure);
```

The problem is with makeList method. I don't know why is this not working.

Comment: You are defining a function `resultDisplayArray` (why I don't know) and then you never call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you needed to return "resultDisplayArray(arr)" instead of "resultDisplayArray", and place a "let" in front of "element"

```
const result = {
  success: ["max-length", "no-amd", "prefer-arrow-functions"],
  failure: ["no-var", "var-on-top", "linebreak"],
  skipped: ["id-blacklist", "no-dup-keys"]
};

function makeList(arr) {
  "use strict";
 
 
  // Only change code below this line
  const resultDisplayArray = (arr) =>{
    let failure = [];
   for (let element of arr) {
      failure.push(`<li class="text-warning">${element}</li>`);
    }
  
    return failure;
    
  };
  // Only change code above this line

  return resultDisplayArray(arr);
}

const resultDisplayArray = makeList(result.failure);
console.log(resultDisplayArray);
```

Comment: Unfortunate that you needed to change code below the comment that says: `// Only change code above this line`